# Sumar los dígitos del resultado de otra función en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Primero, he creado esta función para convertir ciertas letras a números:

```
function convertLetras(palabra){
            switch(palabra){
                case "a": return 1;
                break;
                default: return 'unknown';
   }
}
```

Ahora, deseo sumar los dígitos del resultado de la siguiente función:

```
 var sumaL;

 function sumLetras() {
   //guardo los valores generados desde un input de id 'palabra'
   var palabra = document.getElementById('palabra').value;

   sumaL = 0;

   for (var i = 0; i < palabra.length; i++) {
     sumaL = sumaL + convertLetras(palabra.charAt(i));
   }
   document.write(sumaL);
 }
```

El resultado de esta función es un número asignado a la variable **sumaL**.

La función que debo crear para conseguir ejecutar desde el botón del form la suma de los dígitos de la variable sumaL, sería ¿cual?:

```
function sumaLetrasF(){


}


<form>
        <label>
            Ingrese la palabra:
            <input type="text" id="palabra">
        </label>
        <label>
            <button onclick="sumLetrasF()">Enviar</button>
        </label>

    </form>
```

Deseo sumar los dígitos de este número en una nueva función y a través de un botón ejecutarla. Como tendría que hacer?
Desde ya, muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: En tu función tienes que usar return sumaL. Tienes que usar una variable antes de l función sumLetras. Por ejemplo var resultado = sumLetras()... De esta forma sumaL será asignado a var resultado al final de tu función y puedes utilizar ‘resultado’ en otra función. Lo siento por no poder poner la solución completa, estoy escribiendo desde el móvil

Comment: Y en caso quiera ejecutar esto desde un botón, cómo podría hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido bien tu pregunta quieres sumar los dígitos de `sumaL`.

```
function sumardigitos(sumaL){
 sumaL=sumaL+""; 
    suma=0;
 for(var i=0; i<sumaL.length;i++){
  suma+=parseInt(sumaL[i]);
}
document.write(suma);
return suma;
}
```

Convertimos a String la variable `sumaL` y trabajamos con ella recorriendo cada posición y sumándoselo a otra variable `suma`. He añadido un document.write para que te pinte el resultado. Sería mejor hacerlo con un innerHTML pero para eso tengo que conocer el código html.

Para poner la función en un boton simplemente crea un boton en html y pon el atributo onclick llamando a la función. `onclick="sumardigitos(sumaL)"`. Como parámetro pásale la otra función que tienes, o quítale el parámetro si ves que no te sirve porque lo vas a almacenar en variables globales. Tendrías que quitarlo en el atributo onclick y también en la función claro.

Comment: pero cómo podría ejecutar esa función que proporcionaste, desde un botón?

Comment: Le quité el parámetro sumaL a la función sumarDigitos y al botón le puse onclick="sumarDigitos()". No funcionó. El resultado es el valor 0.

Comment: ¿Cómo se ejecuta la otra función que tienes? ¿Cómo devuelve o almacena el valor? El problema será que no está cogiendo el valor de la variable sumaL de la otra función. Comparte el código completo y lo veo.

Comment: Sí perfecto @Miguel27, ya lo hize!

Comment: Perfecto, si te sirvió acepta la respuesta como la solución. Así me ayudas a mí.

Comment: No me sirvió @Miguel27, te decía que ya pasé el código completo. No me refería a la solución. Con seguridad daré votos positivos si consigo esa solución que tu de seguro debes saber.

Comment: Podrías ayudar? Tu respuesta no sirvió.

Comment: La función que puse hace lo que pedías. El problema es que con el código que pusiste no entiendo bien lo que pretendes. Deberías repasar el funcionamiento de las funciones y el del `switch`. Las dos funciones que pusiste con el código que hay no se ejecutan en ningún momento. Por otro lado el switch de dentro de la función `convertLetras` siempre te devolverá "unknown", salvo que el parámetro "palabra" que le pasas sea una "a" solo, que te devuelve 1.

Comment: 1. Lo que pretendo es convertir primero una palabra a números con esa función o con otra recomendada.
2. Sumar los dígitos de esa palabra.(Hacer un array con esos dígitos y sumarlos). 
3. Volver a sumar los dígitos de ese array anterior. 
4. Ejecutar esta función mediante un onclick.